# How can I handle this overlayed frame(modal?) ? (with python, selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, modal-dialog

I'd like to write code for login this page,
[page](https://www.cos.com/ko-kr/index.html)

and when I click login, pop up login page. (maybe it called 'modal', right?)

So I wrote code like this,

'''

```
# Click the sign in button
sign_in_link = browser.find_element_by_class_name("a-link.sign-in.menu-link.open-lightbox")
sign_in_link.click()
time.sleep(2)

#login
email_input = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="signInFrame"]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[1]/input')
email_input.click()
pyperclip.copy("my id")
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")
```

'''

But it doesnt work. Error message was

***selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="signInFrame"]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[1]/input"}***

How can I revise this code?
(This is my first question about coding in my lifetime, so maybe it's not enough for you to understand,
then I will add some information about this question.)

Thanks for read my word

Comment: Stackoverflow is not code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inspecting the HTML code we can see that the login form is contained inside an `iframe` element with `id=loginFrame`.

[image]

So in order to be able to interact with the login form, we first have to switch to the `iframe` by running the following code

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "loginFrame")))
```

After this you can run the code `email_input = ...` and click on the element

Comment: wow it works very well!!!! i really appreciate your answer :) thank you!!